# Match multiple file extensions in npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have an npm script where I want to match both `ts` and `tsx` file extensions... something like below:

```
"test": "mocha ..... app/test/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}"
```

However, the above syntax doesn't work.  What's the correct syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your pattern is correct. Your problem is that your shell is attempting to expand your glob for you instead of letting `mocha` expand it.

To fix this, you need to double-quote your glob (note that double-quotes must be JSON-escaped with `\`):

```
"test": "mocha ..... \"app/test/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}\""
```

Single quotes will also work (and won't need JSON-escaped) if you don't care about Windows support.