# package.json - pathname pattern for .ts .tsx .js .jsx

Tags: javascript, package.json

I am trying to write a npm script that goes trought all of my src files and tests (lints) files that end in either `.ts` `.tsx` `.js` or `.jsx`. So the linter should test all of these (and only these).

What I have so far:
`"lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0 --ext .js \"src/**/*.ts*\""`

- Does this test both `.ts` and `.tsx` files?
- How do I write a pattern for multiple file types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
"lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0 --ext .js \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\""
```

As can be seen [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45949796/match-multiple-file-extensions-in-npm-script)

As far as I know, that is the only way to handle multiple file extensions. When using a asteriks, i get the feedback "The system cannot find the path specified."